# Uncaught (in promise) Error: The query requires an index

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

I get this error once I added the Where method, but it works without the Where clause.  In collection every document has Boolean called "status".

```
db.firestore().collection('jobs').where("status","==",true).orderBy("createDate").limit(10).get().then(querySnapshot =>{

        })
      })
```

All Help is Appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're querying on two fields (`status` and `createDate`), there needs to be a composite index on those two fields. Indices on individual fields are automatically created, but composite indexes are only created when you ask for them.

The error message should contain a link directly to the console to complete that task. If that's not the case, you can create it [here](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/firestore/indexes).

Comment: thanks! it worked. solution was right there in console.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore query on more than two fields requires a composite index on that two filed.

So you have to create composite index `status` and `createDate`.You will get the error like following when you don't have an index.

```
ERROR Error: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/admin-e8a7b/database/firestore/indexes?create_index=EgR0ZW1wGgcKA3VpZBACGg0KCXN0YXJ0ZWRBdBADGgwKCF9fbmFtZV9fEAM
at new FirestoreError (vendor.bundle.js:19925)
```

So when you click this link in error index will be created automatically.

You can also manually create index from [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/YOURPROJECT/database/firestore/indexes)

**To combine the equality operator (==) with a range comparison (<, <=, >, or >=), make sure to create a custom index.**