# Why is docs being called on null on my streambuilder when I use .where()?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple Streambuilder like this:

```
class InventoryScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InventoryScreenState createState() => _InventoryScreenState();
}

class _InventoryScreenState extends State<InventoryScreen> {
  Stream userstream;
  String fuser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getStream();
  }

  CollectionReference categcollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('categories');

  getStream() async {
    var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    setState(() {
      userstream = categcollection
          .where('userId', isEqualTo: firebaseUser.uid)
          .orderBy('createdAt')
          .snapshots();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: DrawerNavigation(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Title Here'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context)
              .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewCategory()));
        },
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: userstream,
        builder: (ctx, categSnapshot) {          
          if (categSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          final categDocs = categSnapshot.data.docs;
          return ListView.builder(
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: categDocs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                //some code here....
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and it returns this error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The getter 'docs' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: docs
The relevant error-causing widget was
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>
lib\screens\inventory_screen.dart:53
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

This code will work perfectly if I remove `.where('userId', isEqualTo: firebaseUser.uid)` in `getStream()`. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

I tried changing the contents of .where() into different document keys and add manual values, and what happens is it will show the query results on the emulator screen for less than a second and then throw out the docs was called on null exception.

Any guidance will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: add `print(categSnapshot)` as a first line of your `builder` - what do you see on the logs?

Comment: Hi Pskink - here's what I got:

I/flutter (11906): categSnapshot: AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null)
I/flutter (11906): categSnapshot: AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>(ConnectionState.active, Instance of 'QuerySnapshot', null)

Comment: so you have valid `QuerySnapshot` data when connection state != `ConnectionState.waiting` , maybe try another `print(categSnapshot.data)` just before calling `final categDocs = categSnapshot.data.docs;`

Comment: that one just returned this: I/flutter (11906): null

Comment: If you applied some error checking to the query, the Firestore SDK would give you an error message saying exactly what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48698821/2668529

apparently:

> Since you're querying on two fields , there needs to be a composite index on those two fields. Indices on individual fields are automatically created, but composite indexes are only created when you ask for them.

That means you can only use either where() or orderBy(). You can't use them both at the same time without creating an Index in Firestore first.