# Composite index firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using two different queries to order my data and putting a where clause. I need a composite index. I am also using `limitToLast`

```
const tradesRef = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("trades")
    .orderBy("time", "asc")
    .where("type", "==", "fiveMinutes")
    .limit(15);
```

I have created a composite index such as:
[image: New Composite Index]

I am still getting this error:

[image: console error]

Answer (score 0):

The fields indexed seem to be correct but you are not running a collection group query so have you tried setting the query scope to just "Collection" instead of "Collection group"?

Also try deleting current index and creating new index directly using the link in error.

Comment: Still giving the same error

Comment: @HusnainMehmood can you share a screenshot of the new index? Also you have deleted the older one right ?

Comment: Screenshot updated. And yes, previous one deleted.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48698821/15774176) :

> Since you're querying on two fields (status and createDate), there
> needs to be a composite index on those two fields. Indices on
> individual fields are automatically created, but composite indexes are
> only created when you ask for them. The error message should contain a
> link directly to the console to complete that task. If that's not the
> case, you can create it [here](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/firestore/indexes).

For more information related to how firestore manages indexes, you can refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/indexing?hl=lt).

Comment: @Husnain Mehmood Posted an answer, is it helpful?